# Eloquent Pivot sentence

Tags: laravel, loops, eloquent, pivot

I dont understand well Eloquent pivot sentence
I have **3 tables**, *proyect* ( id , name ) , *users* (id, name)  and *proyectUsers* (id, user_id, proyect_id)

**Proyect model**

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Users::class, 'projectUsers',  'id_proyect', 'user_id');
    }
```

**View**

```
@foreach( $proyect->users as $user)
    {{$user->name}} 
    @if(!$loop->last)
        ,
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Actually works, but If I see [Laravel pivot relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) I don't use it any pivot sentence.

```
foreach ($proyect->users as $user) {
    echo $user->pivot->name;
    @if(!$loop->last)
        ,
    @endif
}
```

If I want to do correctly I have to use this code? I do it correctly?

Comment: Well you are defining a name column on your user table. However that relationship should return a collection. So you would have to iterate through the name objects to access the name attribute. Your user table should not have a name column if you are wanting a many to many relationship.

Comment: I write 3 tables as simple as I could. I have more field but I think it is enough to understand my "problem".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're doing it correctly, you don't need to use `->pivot` here.

However, you may want to use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) for one line solution instead of using `foreach` loop:

```
{{ implode(', ', $proyect->users->pluck('name')->toArray()) }}
```

Comment: Thank you, is other option.